# select part of url string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

If have the following string with a unique element in it. This unique element I need to extract from this string and save it as an variable. The part that I need to extract is: Proto-1088.

```
"{"account":"123456","n":{"Score":"Bad","Ticket":"https://test.test2.com/browse/Proto-1088"},"2":{"Score":"GOOD"}}
```

I have tried to use the `TRIM` function in MySQL but this didn't work since the number in `Proto` changes.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  5.7 has JSON functions that would be happy to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only URL in the string you could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  '"{"account":"123456","n":
  {"Score":"Bad","Ticket":"https://test.test2.com/browse/Proto-1088"},"2":{"Score":"GOOD"}}', 
  '/', -1),
'"',1)
```

Explanation:

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)` finds the index of  `count` occurrence of `delim` (counting from left if `count` is positive, from right if negative) and returns everything past that index (going left if `count` is positive, right if negative).

So I used `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `count=-1` to extract everything to the right of the last occurrence of `'/'` and then took everything to the right of the first occurrence of `'"` using `count=1`.